# Error in mySQL form submission

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I'm working on a Student Registration System, where student login using username & password assigned to them (login mechanism works fine) after login a landing page display student name, user_id, and department (using echo function from mysql) then he is asked to select courses to register, after submission I need to update courses on mysql against the user_id (which was shown on previous page) the selected courses get update on mysql but only if I define the `user_id` e.g.:

```
mysql_select_db('school',$conn);

$fresh = $_REQUEST["fresh"]; 
$user_id= $_REQUEST["user_id"]; 

$sql = "UPDATE `rasmp_accounts`
SET `fresh`='$fresh' WHERE `user_id`='001' ";
```

but not work when I define the WHERE condition as:

```
mysql_select_db('school',$conn);

$fresh = $_REQUEST["fresh"]; 
$user_id= $_REQUEST["user_id"]; 

$sql = "UPDATE `rasmp_accounts`
SET `fresh`='$fresh' WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' ";
```

The reason could be that user_id (which was displayed on the previous page) was not the form field but the echo function, therefore the `$user_id= $_REQUEST["user_id"];` might not fetch the user_id from previous page. Is there's any way by which I could fetch the user_id from previous page and link it to the submit page so it will only update courses with matching `user_id`?

Will be highly grateful for any help :(

Comment: how do you move from one page to the next? You need to either store all the data and retrieve it on the 2nd page again, or pass on the same variable again (ie. via a hidden input)

Comment: you can use `hidden field` in your `form` and put your `user_id` in it

Comment: Can you show your form page & `echo $sql;` and check what `$user_id` values received.?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking if it is null or not?

Comment: what if `$user_id` is `' OR 1 = 1`

Comment: Prepared statements (in [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli)) would resolve this problem of SQL injection immediately

Comment: Please edit your post to include the form from the previous page as well.

Comment: Dear Satish Sharma, thanks a lot for a big help. It works after using hidden field in form! Lot of Blessings :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see what you mean without seeing all your code (previous page), but if you want to pull something from REQUEST['user_id'] you must put something in there. Either in a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value ="<?php echo $user_id ?>">
```

Or pull it from $_GET['user_id'] by doing

```
<form method="post" action="myProcess.php?user_id=<?php echo $user_id ?>">
```